# Trying to install Ubuntu with Windows 10 in GPT with early UEFI bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have a GPT disk in which I had Windows 10 along with Mac OS X. The system is a 2011 motherboard with one of the early UEFIs that almost looks like normal BIOS and acts kinda weird sometimes. I erased the hfs partition which left me with the normal win 10 partitions (recovery, the 100mb fat, another 16mb partition and the ntfs where windows resides).

I decided to install ubuntu, for which I tried two things:

First time, all normal, boot partition, swap partition, root partition and a home partition in a second hard drive. That failed at boot with "normal.mod not found" error. Tried reinstalling grub but it said that without the BIOS partition it wouldn't do it. I kinda figured that the 100MB fat partition was the one used for EFI stuff, but apparently I don't know much about UEFI.

Reinstalled this time without a /boot partition but with the BIOS partition of around 100-200MB. Now at boot I get "Filesystem unknown" and running `ls` from the grub rescue does not show all the partitions.

I'm at loss. I rather not erase everything because I don't have a backup of the windows partition.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You really don't know enough about UEFI. Start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: You should boot the Ubuntu media in the same way the already installed Windows is which is most likely UEFI mode. How it boots is how it installs. You tried to install in BIOS mode in a GTP drive for which a bios_grub partition is required.

Comment: Ok, you were right. I managed to boot the installer in UEFI mode, but the problem persists.

I installed it with ext4 partitions and I still have the same unknown filesystem and if I run ls I only see (hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0, msdos1)
:(

I feel like I'm getting closer though. I managed to install gentoo as my first linux system in the past so I have to get this shit running hah

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it running. The key was to boot the UEFI version of the installer. I had to wipe everything.

The second thing was that there is a legacy grub installed in the MBR of the second hard drive and I got confused about the disk names and didn't notice it was trying to boot from that one. Just selecting the proper one after the reinstall made it happen.

Thank you everybody.